# How do I make a counter only from logic gates?

Tags: counter

What I want to make is a circuit using only logic gates made from transistors, and not using any IC.

What I want to do:

- There is 1 button and 8 LEDs.
- When I press the button the first LED turns on.
- When I press again the second led turns on and the first one is off.
- If I press again the 2nd turns off and the 3rd one is on and so on.
- When the 8th is on and I press the button, it turns off and the 1st one turns on.

Edit: I didn't had much time, and I made this : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDnuwpmMbkCDTSN9Rp9RtZGqToKvfi5S/view?usp=sharing Its it works somewhat, but if a bulb lights up the bulb before it don't turn off. I tried to connect the A output after it and to the reset button with an OR gate to its "reset" instead of connecting it to the B output of the previous.: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mzq8qIRuFnLLbg0kcDwnM-36qrQj2Z_V/view?usp=sharing But it doesn't work. What should I do ?

Comment: Show your most recent attempt.

Comment: I couldn't make anything, I tried but I couldn't

Comment: Start using Google search, search for "counter circuit" and select the images tab. Then observe tens of counter circuits. Yes, these use some flip-flops so find a schematic for those also using "flip-flop circuit". Those might use for example NAND gates, again search... **ALSO**, this isn't something anyone can do without at least some **studying** into the subject. You can't just design any circuit without proper education.

Comment: Hope you have alotta transistors on-hand.....  That's gonna be a big circuit if you don't use IC's.

Comment: BTW, I think what you're looking for isn't a "counter", your description sounds like a "shift register" to me.   You might Google that instead....              https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_5.html

Comment: Also **not using any IC** is something that can be done but if you have to **ask** then I doubt that you have the required skills. If you want to **fail and be frustrated about electronics** then what you're doing now is the way to go. You set too much restrictions (no ICs), don't have the knowledge (cannot come up with anything) and want something **very complex** (the function isn't complex, even **easy to do** when using a microcontroller, you make it complex by not wanting to use ICs).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and own findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is a breeze to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: I have knowledge for this, I've already made logic gate circuits from transistors, even some very complex, I tried search in google but i found nothing, this counter is the only thing that i have no idea how to do

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you at least show us your ideas. Otherwise, just google for "discrete d flip flop" and work from there. There are plenty of useful links.

Comment: "*What should I do?*" Add the schematics into your question, not in external links. That way we don't have to follow links to understand your question and the question will still make sense when the links die. Note that you have already accepted an answer indicating that your question has been answered to your satisfaction. Your update indicates that it hasn't. You can un-accept to attract more answers.

Comment: Please don't include links to schematics, but include the schematics themselves. BTW those schematics are not very clear.

Comment: So, Thank you all really much for your help (even after some answers and comment I just got disappointed and hopeless) , but I think this isn't the website and this isn't the community that can help to me with this and with other things, I guess that I have to do it on my own, just like another time. I didn't asked what I should do different, should I do it or not, do I have the knowledge for this "project", I asked how I can make what I wrote in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counter you are describing appears to be just a an 8 element shift register with the output of each register hooked to one LED, and the clock connected to a button.

For the clock to work you need to make some sort of a de-bounce circuit so you only get one clock edge each time you press the button.

The shift register is just a bunch of D-flip-flops set up so that the output of one feeds the input of the next one.  So making the shift register ultimately boils down to figuring out how to make a D-flip-flop.

D-flip-flops can be made from a modified bi-stable latch circuit.  The basic bi-stable latch is made from two transistors and four resistors.  It can be modified with an extra transistor to add clocking and a data input.

This link shows how.
https://hackaday.io/project/164485-flip-flops-using-discrete-transistors

You would also need a reset button to guarantee the initial state of the flip-flops (since you want one of them to be on, and all the others to be off).

Comment: Thank you very much ! That is what I was looking for. Someone finally understood what I said.

Answer (score 2):

You want a system that has "memory" — it needs to remember its state from one moment to the next, and move from one state to another state when you press your button.

This means that you need one or more memory devices. The simplest memory element is a flip-flop, and the simplest flip-flop can be created by cross-connecting two NAND or two NOR gates.

Start by building a single flip-flop and playing around with it. Then you can learn how to combine multiple flip-flops to build more complex circuits. The topic is far too broad to get into here, but there are plenty of resources available on the web.

For counters, shift registers, and similar circuits, the key concept is "edge triggering". You can build edge-triggered flip-flops using gates (a DFF is either six 3-input gates or eight 2-input gates), or you can get the same effect by using a two-phase clock system.

Comment: If you want that information in video format, search for Ben Eater on YouTube. Transistors to CPUs playlist - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTu3LwpF6XI&list=PLoiyKtB6KImsKnw95ho88aPkw3PkqvL5s

Comment: I've already made a memory like this, I'm currently working on a 8 or 16  bit memory, which made from NOR gates, a reader and a writer for it, this circuit that i want to create is for the writer, selecting which bite to write 1 or 0 to(so there is only 3 button). Everything done except for this counter, I had also had this idea but I couldn't make anything functional.